# Why this insert statement fails?

Tags: sql-server, database

Suppose, I have **database A** and **database B**, both contains **table t1, t2** etc.

Some statement (we name it **statement1**) like

```
@declare ...
@declare ...
...
end
```

is populating **t1** in **database A**.

I want to populate same data in **t1** of **database B**.

While I was trying this sql in **database B**

```
insert into t1
statement1
```

but,it fails

What to do for inerting data ?

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? Can you post the script?

Comment: I don't understand. What error do you get?

Comment: Because you are missing an `s` in "`inert`"?

Comment: the error is "invalid syntax near Declare" @Backs

Answer (score 1):

you can use to insert data from databaseA to databaseB, assuming both of them in the same server.

```
insert into databaseB.<schemaname>.t1 SELECT * FROM databaseA.<schemaname>.t1
```